# por qué mi proyecto en mi servidor web no redirecciona?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

Tengo el siguiente problema, en mi local todo funciona bien, pero al subir mi proyecto al servidor web no me redirecciona al crear las sesiones, y tampoco me muestra ningún error. el código de mis files es el siguiente:
primero tengo el `form` donde mando los parámetros para evaluar el inicio de sesión

```
    <form action="phpsew/validar_usuario_sew.php"  id="form-session" method="post">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario">                    
                </div>
            <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="contrase帽a">
                </div>



                <div class="row align-items-center remember">
                    <input type="checkbox">Recordarme
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn">
                </div>
            </form>
```

El file donde se valida esta dentro de una carpeta que se llama `phpsew`, llamado `validar_usuario_sew.php` el cual contiene el siguiente código

```
   <?php
  error_reporting();
  include('conexion.php');

session_start();

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$nombre' AND clave = 
    '$password'";
     $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

     $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

     $nombre_usuario=$row['nombre'];

    if($row['usuario'] == $nombre && $row['clave'] == $password && $row['tipo'] ==1){
    

       header("location:files_id_sew.php"); 
         $_SESSION['admin'] = $nombre_usuario;
    
      }
     else if($row['usuario'] == $nombre && $row['clave'] == $password && $row['tipo'] 
    ==0) 
    {
 
    header("location:Docs_person.php");
    $_SESSION['comun'] = $nombre_usuario;
    }
    else
    { 
   ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert("¡Los datos que ingresaste no corrrespoonden a ninguna cuenta!");
  window.location.href='../index.php';
  </script>
  <?php

   }
 ?>
```

Y es aquí donde está el problema, la conexión a la base de datos la realiza correctamente, y los archivos a los que quiero que me redireccione están en la misma carpeta, pero no hace nada, solo se queda la página en blanco, y no muestra nada de error, pueden decirme donde está el error por favor. saludos a todos y gracias.

Comment: session_start() tiene que la primera cosa despues del <?php  Ha buscado en el log para errores?

Comment: no, tampoco así funciona, ya lo había considerado, y no sé que es log para errores? @Duston

Comment: Tambien le surge que use parametros para su busqueda para evitar ataques de SQL Inyeccion.

Comment: por el momento quiero ver que me redireccione, y posterior a eso me enfocaré en la seguridad

Comment: Por que tiene <?php } al fin del archivo?

Comment: para cerrar el último else

Comment: <?php no cierre nada.

Comment: sí, solo que me faltaba la etiqueta de cierre, pero continúa sín funcionar

Comment: el direccionesmiento de js sí lo hace, los que no me hace son los de php, con el    header("location:files_id_sew.php");  ni con el header("location:Docs_person.php");

Comment: Y los bloques de esos dos codigos no los agregaste a tu pregunta... Ya que aqui solo se mira una redireccion por js

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la `header()` función para enviar un nuevo encabezado HTTP, pero este debe enviarse al navegador antes de cualquier HTML o texto (es decir, antes de la `<!DOCTYPE ...>`

Puede utilizar el método alternativo http_redirect($url);que necesita que se instale el paquete [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http)

**Recuerda que PHP siempre se ejecuta en el lado del servidor, nunca en el lado del cliente**.